# How to extract lat / long coordinates from 2 numpy arrays in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I basically have 2 arrays, one containing Lattitude values, one Longitude. What I want is to extract those that meet a certain requirement .

```
xLong = np.extract(abs(Long-requirement)<0.005,Long)
xLat = np.extract(abs(Lat-requirement)<0.005,Lat)
```

Lat and Long are numpy arrays.

However, I only want to get those coordinates that both lat/long meet the requirement and I'm not sure how to do it .

If it's possible, I need to use numpy functions since I'm looking for optimization as well. I know that I can iterate through all using a for and just add to different array but that would take a lot of time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this with [boolean indexing.](https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/Indexing.html#Boolean-indexing)  Whenever you create an boolean array the same shape as your array of interest, you can get just the `True` values out by indexing with the boolean array.  I assume below that `Long` and `Lat` are the same size; if they're not the code will throw an exception.

```
# start building the boolean array.  long_ok and lat_ok will be the same
# shape as xLong and xLat.
long_ok = np.abs(Long - requirement) < 0.005
lat_ok = np.abs(Lat - requirement) < 0.005

# both_ok is still a boolean array which is True only where 
# long and lat are both in the region of interest
both_ok = long_ok & lat_ok

# now actually index into the original arrays.
long_final = Long[both_ok]
lat_final = Lat[both_ok]
```

Comment: Yes, they are the same size. Thank you for the answer, code works nice